# Inserting class into database through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, css, database, interaction

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8" />
<title> data input form </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/form.css"/>
</head>

<body>

    <h1> Insert data here</h1>

    <form method="get" action="insert-data.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
        <fieldset>
            <ul>
                <li><label> English Word <input type="text" name="englishWord"/>                                 </label></li>
                <li><label> Beginner German <input type="text" name="beginnerGerman"/>      </label></li>
            </ul>
            <input type="submit" value="add new record" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <? php

    echo $newrecord;

    ?>
</body>
</html>

<?php
//connect to database
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "mypass";
$database = "dictionary";
$table = "engdic";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$database") or die(mysql_error());

$englishWord = $_GET['englishWord'];
$beginnerGerman=$_GET['beginnerGerman'];
$mysql = "INSERT INTO $table (englishWord,beginnerGerman) VALUES ('$englishWord','<div class='beginner_german'>$beginnerGerman</div>')";
if(!mysql_query($mysql))
die(mysql_error());

echo "data inserted";
mysql_close();
?>
//INSIDE DATABASE 
<div class=`beginner_german`>Beginner German Word</div>
```

So I will have input form where user will add translation words in to database, when user will add lets say word Apple, it will also add div with css class to database.So that way when another user will search for word Apple I can style it with css class. my problem is 
when I am trying to add div with class="beginner_german" I am geting error in php, when I am using clas='beginner_german' it inserts in database fine but when I cant call the css class, because syntax must be class="beginner_german". So what is the solution. Thank you for your time.

Comment: **Unrelated:** Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please escape user input properly. Also, there is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: you are out-putting an undefined variable $newrecord. First error.

Answer (score 0):

you need backslashes for your double quote

```
$mysql = "INSERT INTO $table (englishWord,beginnerGerman) VALUES ('$englishWord','<div class=\"beginner_german\">$beginnerGerman</div>')";
```